# LuaLaTeX macOS font mystery (fontbook Montserrat)

Tags: fonts, luatex

I have an odd mystery on my hand.  I installed the google fonts Montserrat and a couple of other fonts as user fonts on macos.  All of them work out of the box on lualatex, except Montserrat.  (I want to use the semi-bold version eventually, so I am not working with the texlive fonts.)  the test file is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

%% tries from fontbook ... works
%% \newfontfamily{\montserrat}{Ubuntu}
%% \newfontfamily{\montserrat}{Andika}

%% tries from Fontbook ... fails
%%\newfontfamily{\montserrat}{Montserrat}
%%\newfontfamily{\montserrat}{Montserrat Regular}
%%\newfontfamily{\montserrat}{Montserrat-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\montserrat}{Montserrat SemiBold}  %% tries from Fontbook ... fails

%% tries from explicit ttf file ... fails
%%\setmainfont[Path=./fonts/]{Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf}

\begin{document}

\montserrat

Hello!  This is my font.

\end{document}
```

my macos fontbook user fonts are [image: userfonts]

I have tried every spelling combination [with dash, without dash] I could think of.  even stranger, I think it used to work a few weeks ago.  since then, many things changed, including my having installed and deinstalled other fonts.  it's probably something simple.  but how do I trace this?  are there methods to

1. list all fonts accessible to lualatex ?
2. show what files lualatex was looking for (with directory, etc.) when I requested a specific named font?

sincerely, .iaw

Comment: probably the font has an error. Remove it and try if the montserrat from texlive works.

Comment: You could try getting the fonts from https://github.com/JulietaUla/Montserrat (Google doesn’t always have the latest versions).

Comment: removing the Montserrat font from the Fontbook made it work.  alas, the lualatex font error message could use some improvements....I will try to figure out how to file a suggestion...

Comment: the "font not found" message is from fontspec. So an issue should go there. To search for fonts you can use the tool https://ctan.org/pkg/luafindfont.